# React input placeholder - type-writer animation?

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm trying to add a typewriting animation as a placeholder in my form `input` in react.

I have tried different npm packages and techniques but nothing covers animation inside of `placeholder` in particular. Any tips or ideas that you can share with me?

```
<input
      className="search-input"
      required
      type="text"
      value={searchValue}
      placeholder="type a name"
      onChange={handleChange} />
```

Answer (score 4):

You could try something like this 
Typescript:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";


export const AnimatedInput = ({placeholder: passedPlaceholder = "", ...passedProps}: React.InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const [placeholder, setPlaceholder] = useState(passedPlaceholder.slice(0, 0));
    const [placeholderIndex, setPlaceholderIndex] = useState(0);


    useEffect(() => {
        const intr = setInterval(() => {
            setPlaceholder(passedPlaceholder.slice(0, placeholderIndex));
            if (placeholderIndex + 1 > passedPlaceholder.length) {
                setPlaceholderIndex(0)
            } else {
                setPlaceholderIndex(placeholderIndex + 1)
            }
        }, 150);
        return () => {
            clearInterval(intr)
        }
    },);


    return <input {...passedProps} placeholder={placeholder}/>
};
```

Javascript:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";


export const AnimatedInput = ({placeholder: passedPlaceholder = "", ...passedProps}) => {
    const [placeholder, setPlaceholder] = useState(passedPlaceholder.slice(0, 0));
    const [placeholderIndex, setPlaceholderIndex] = useState(0);


    useEffect(() => {
        const intr = setInterval(() => {
            setPlaceholder(passedPlaceholder.slice(0, placeholderIndex));
            if (placeholderIndex + 1 > passedPlaceholder.length) {
                setPlaceholderIndex(0)
            } else {
                setPlaceholderIndex(placeholderIndex + 1)
            }
        }, 150);
        return () => {
            clearInterval(intr)
        }
    },);


    return <input {...passedProps} placeholder={placeholder}/>
};
```

Use:

```
<AnimatedInput placeholder="type a name"/>
```

Comment: you can use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval` because `useEffect` will always run after state update like when you do `setPlaceholder(...)`